# CCS811 Gas sensor With raspberry pi and a relay

Tags: python, sensors, raspberry-pi4, relayjs

dears stackoverflow community, I need an instructions guide with python script to make a project to measure the co2 concentration in room and when the concentration is high the relay should switch a light on, so can anyone be kindful and help me to find the instructions guide, thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't think there's just one tutorial for both of those, but here's a CCS tutorial: https://how2electronics.com/measure-co2-tvoc-using-ccs811-gas-sensor-arduino/ and here's a tutorial on using a relay with an arduino: https://www.instructables.com/Controlling-120-240-VAC-with-a-relay-using-arduino/

Comment: But those instructions for arduino and not raspberry pi